# Can you save a debug configuration und use it again later? Or export breakpoints? How does firefox/google chrome store breakpoint informations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox, configuration

How can I reuse my breakpoints? Especially log and/or cond breakpoints. Is there an add-on (firefox or google chrome) to do this?

[image]

Often I need the debug configurations to document my results and it would be easier to just append a file instead of doing many copy/paste operations.

Where/how does firefox/google chrome store this information?

Comment: You could actually control this with Javascript code..  eg.  Maybe store a var called debugmode,.  then you could do ->  `if (debugmode) { if (somecond) debugger; }`   If you then have your debug console open, if will break on this line.

Comment: @Keith Okay, this is the version where I already know where to set my breakpoints. This means that I work out my breakpoints in the debugger and transfer them into the JavaScript code for the next use. Many copy/paste operations.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do.   If you bundle your Javascript it's even possible for you to create a debug version and none debug version with the `if (debugmode)` taken out.  And of course placing in Javascript means if line number change, or even what files it gets bundled into,  you will never loose your debug points.. ;)

Comment: @Keith  That helps me, but I'm looking for a more automated solution of retrieving this information in the first place. The developer tools must somehow manage this information. I hope somebody knows something about it.