# Is there a way to save all Javascript debugger breakpoints so that I can resume my debugging later without having to reset them?

Tags: javascript, debugging, chromium

**Update:** It turns out that using private browsing is the reason why my breakpoints wouldn't save, and that does makes sense considering that breakpoints are tied to a JS file which is part of a fully-qualified URL. I am going to assume there's no way to actually save this part of the browser state locally and just continue to use a normal browsing session.

Original question:

I think the closest match to my question is here:

[Can you save a debug configuration und use it again later? Or export breakpoints? How does firefox/google chrome store breakpoint informations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414848/can-you-save-a-debug-configuration-und-use-it-again-later-or-export-breakpoints)

However, it's a few years old and has no answers, so I am asking a more specific one here.

When I am debugging complex Javascript in Chromium browsers, I end up having breakpoints set across various JS files. When I want to quit for a while and resume later, closing the browser causes me to lose all breakpoints and I have to reset them on the next session.

Is there a way to save the current debugger state so that I can reload all my old breakpoints? I do *not* want to use the `debugger` command because I may want to disable/re-enable breakpoints.

I will also add that I am also using Javascript overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setting the breakpoints and quit the browser (chrome) but I did not lose the breakpoints, try restoring default settings of chrome dev tool.

Comment: Ah, it seems that the issue may be that I am using incognito mode. I just opened a normal browser, set a breakpoint, and it persisted when I reopened. I won't go into detail as to why I am using incognito mode, but I need to, so I will edit my OP with this information.